# Salesforce picklist values not showing up in picklist

Tags: salesforce

I have added values to a Custom Object multi-select picklist as well as a Standard Object multi-select picklist (both fields are custom) and the new values fail to show up on the record as a choice in the picklist.  No field level security was changed or any visibility settings were altered.  Anyone know why these new values will not show?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the Record Type settings for the standard and custom objects.  Click on the record type and you'll see the "Picklists Available for Editing" section.  From there you should be able to add the new picklist values.

The picklist values at the field level are like a master list.  Using record types you can allow only a subset of the list to show up.

Comment: Thank you!  This was spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: In the case of field dependencies, you need to add the individual picklist values to each dependent value for each stage.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to the "Sales Process" (search) and then choose the opportunity type I was editing. I could then add the field picklist value in.

SF does seem overly complex at times!